# In how many ways can a salesperson visit $15$ different offices during the week?

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the following question:

[image]

I am able to get the answer matched in the book for the part a and b but not part c.

I tried part a as:

```
Factorial[15]
```

> 1,307,674,368,000

Part b as:

```
FactorialPower[15,4]
```

> 32,760

But can't get the book's answer for part c. Please help.

The book is saying the answer to part c should be:

> 13,650

Comment: If she must visit $15$ different offices over those five days, the answer is simply $15!$.  If she is allowed to visit the same office on more than one day, calculate the number of ways she can visit three of the fifteen offices on any given day, then multiply the results.

Answer (score 1):

The book says that you do $\text{FactorialPower}[15,3]*5$. It is a little strange of an answer. It seems like the question is asking how many ways can you visit three different offices on a single day if the day can be any weekday.

Answer (score 0):

So, just to recap:
A) The ways in which to visit the 15 offices is to choose 1 of the 15, then 1 of the 14, then.... 15!

B) To only visit 4 on Monday, choose 1 of the 15, then 1 of the 14, then 1 of the 13, then 1 of the 12.... 15!/11!

C) Given what you reported the answer to be I'm assuming you don't have to visit all 15 offices, just any 3 different ones on a given day. By that logic, on 1 day it would take you 15!/12! ways to visit 3 offices on Monday. With 5 days in the week, it would have 5*(15!/12!) ways in which to visit 3 offices each day.

*Edit* I think Stacker beat me to it.